# PHP Input Stream Truncated at 8192 bytes

Tags: php, stream

I'm working on a project on Symfony 3 as an API and Angular as a front (This is not relevant i think but hey).

When some datas are sent through a PUT request to the server, the data are truncated at 8192 bytes.

I checked for every file configurations (apache files, even cli file, .htacces file... but can't seem to find the issue.)

Weirdest thing, is the issue is on the dev server, the same request on the production server works (all the 18 000~ bytes are sent correctly), so i even tried to take the production server's php configuration file, but even that failed. Just to add on the information, the server runs on php 7.

I'm at a loss, what could i have missed ?

I'm pretty sure the issue comes from a configuration file, or a knowledge i'm missing. So help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: After a bit of forcing... Here is a .tar.gz containing the files requested:

https://files.fm/u/ddghdx36

Comment: Show us your dev server `php.ini` and the `httpd.conf` and the `.htaccess` if you have any.

Comment: Show us the code that is reading this data

Comment: For the reading part, it is simply the Symfony HttpFoundation Request if you know it. I still checked it... Just in case,

The code is initially read with (inside the Request Class):

`$this->content = file_get_contents('php://input');`

I did try something else just in case:
`$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$this->content = fread($input, 1024000);`

And i always get 8192 for this line that i added just after those lines (in both cases):
`var_dump(strlen($this->content));`

I will see what i can do for the file configuration.

Comment: @bluehipy I added a .tar.gz to the requested files. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the cause was incorrect privileges on /tmp directory. Nginx was logging: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory".